# Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power) ID37

Tags: windows, железо, cpu, ос, bios

Столкнулся в журнале событий с таким предупреждением:

> The speed of processor 2 in group 0 is being limited by system firmware. The processor has been in this reduced performance state for 28787 seconds since the last report.

Чем оно может быть вызвано и как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте отключить функцию Intel(R) SpeedStep Technology в конфиге BIOS. И расскажите нам, появляются ли после этого предупреждения.